# I want to return Subcategory (ManyToManyField to Category---another Class) with def __str__(self):

Tags: django, django-models

in the last line i want to return sub category it didn't show any error but it is not show as i am expecting it is showing like

```
NEW ITEM--**Shop.Category.None**
new arrival--**Shop.Category.None**

Adidas Shoes blue color--**Shop.Category.None**
```

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Accessories','Accessories'),
        ('Fashions','Fashions')
               )
  



class IndexProduct(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Subcategory = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.Title + '--' + str(self.Subcategory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django returns a Related Manager (Queryset Manager) when you access a many-to-many field directly.

What this means is that you can probably access what you want through `self.Subcategory.all()`

Something like this should help you get started:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Accessories', 'Accessories'),
        ('Fashions', 'Fashions')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=225, choices=CHOICES)


class IndexProduct(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        names = self.Subcategory.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
        if names:
            return f"{self.email} - {names}"
        return f"{self.email} - No subcategory"
```

Just note though that this can be potentially slow when you have a lot of Categories since you are getting N number of categories every time you access the IndexProduct.

Read here for more information:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield